# Cannot download the pdf - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get an invoice by retrieving the data in my order table, but when I click on the link, it takes me back to my order page without any action.

OrdersController.php

```
public function getPdf(Order $order)
    {
        if (auth()->id() != $order->user_id) {
            return back()->withError("Vous n'avez pas accès à cette commande");
        }
        $products = $order->products;
        $member = User::find(Auth::id());
        $categories = Category::all();

        $pdf = PDF::loadview('invoice/invoice');
        return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf')->with([
            'order' => $order,
            'products' => $products,
            'member' => $member, 
            'categories' => $categories,
        ]);
    }
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/invoice', 'OrdersController@getPdf');
```

Can someone help me? Thank you

Comment: Do you need $order, $products in the invoice? In that case you should pass them at the second argument to loadview()

Comment: yes, I need them but I changed my method and instead of using the invoice view, I used the order view immediately, and now it's working, but thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what kind of PDF class are you using, but you can try in this order:

```
 $pdf = PDF::loadView('invoice/invoice',compact('order','products','member','categories'));

 return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
```

Comment: I changed my method and instead of using the invoice view, I used the order view immediately, and now it's working, but your code really helped with the ```compact``` so thank you very much